# Vue.js - Buefy Modules (Radio btns/ Check Box)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.6

I'm practising back-end in Laravel, and for front-end I'm using Vue.js - Buefy Modules, and I have little problem with Radio and CheckBox.

Here User should choose one of the two offered radio btns:

```
<div class="block">
      <b-radio-group v-model="permissionType">
          <b-radio name="permission_type" value="basic">Basic Permission</b-radio>
          <b-radio name="permission_type" value="crud">CRUD Permission</b-radio>
      </b-radio-group>
  </div>
```

If User click on first btun (Basic) there should appear 3 input fields:

```
<div class="field" v-if="permissionType == 'basic'">
   <label for="display_name" class="label">Name (Display Name)</label>
   <p class="control">
     <input type="text" class="input" name="display_name" id="display_name">
   </p>
</div>

      <div class="field" v-if="permissionType == 'basic'">
        <label for="name" class="label">Slug</label>
        <p class="control">
          <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name">
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="field" v-if="permissionType == 'basic'">
        <label for="description" class="label">Description</label>
        <p class="control">
          <input type="text" class="input" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Describe what this permission does">
        </p>
      </div>
```

If User click on second btn (CRUD) there should appear 1 input, 4 check box btns and table, but they do not appear.

```
<div class="field" v-if="permissionType == 'crud'">
        <label for="resource" class="label">Resource</label>
        <p class="control">
          <input type="text" class="input" name="resource" id="resource" v-model="resource" placeholder="The name of the resource">
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="columns" v-if="permissionType == 'crud'">
        <div class="column is-one-quarter">
          <b-checkbox-group v-model="crudSelected">
            <div class="field">
              <b-checkbox custom-value="create">Create</b-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <b-checkbox custom-value="read">Read</b-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <b-checkbox custom-value="update">Update</b-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <b-checkbox custom-value="delete">Delete</b-checkbox>
            </div>
          </b-checkbox-group>
        </div> <!-- end of .column -->

        <input type="hidden" name="crud_selected" :value="crudSelected">

        <div class="column">
          <table class="table" v-if="resource.length >= 3">
            <thead>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Slug</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="item in crudSelected">
                <td v-text="crudName(item)"></td>
                <td v-text="crudSlug(item)"></td>
                <td v-text="crudDescription(item)"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I've checked Buefy documentation and there were some updates, but when I change code, still not works..

Here is script:

```
  <script>
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            permissionType: 'basic',
            resource: '',
            crudSelected: ['create', 'read', 'update', 'delete']
          },
          methods: {
            crudName: function(item) {
              return item.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1) + " " + app.resource.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + app.resource.substr(1);
            },
            crudSlug: function(item) {
              return item.toLowerCase() + "-" + app.resource.toLowerCase();
            },
            crudDescription: function(item) {
              return "Allow a User to " + item.toUpperCase() + " a " + app.resource.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + app.resource.substr(1);
            }
          }
        }); 
    </script>
```

Here I place original code without changes, if someone could fix this, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add v-model to your radio group, try this and it should work

```
<div class="block">
  <b-radio-group v-model="permissionType">
      <b-radio v-model="permissionType" name="permission_type" native-value="basic">Basic Permission</b-radio>
      <b-radio v-model="permissionType" name="permission_type" native-value="crud">CRUD Permission</b-radio>
  </b-radio-group>
```